# Regex function for a specific location of a symbol

Tags: python

Is there any way to replace the "·" symbol from a text except for the "\n·\n" case?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @MosesKoledoye so `text = re.sub(".·.", "", text)` should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```py
text = re.sub(".·.", "", text)
```

There is one edge case:

```
·Text (Anything but a newline)
```

and

```
Text (Anything but a newline)·
```

That is, a newline on one side and anything else on the other side. This will not be removed, but that isn't stated in the question. If you want to deal with this case, you could do this:

```py
text = re.sub("([^\n]·.)|(.·[^\n])", "", text, re.DOTALL)
```